# Dynamically Create Structs in Golang

Tags: go, struct, unmarshalling

So I am working with an external API, whose responses I wanted to parse. The incoming responses are of a fixed format i.e.

```golang
type APIResponse struct {
    Items          []interface{} `json:"items"`
    QuotaMax       int           `json:"quota_max"`
    QuotaRemaining int           `json:"quota_remaining"`
}
```

So for each response I am parsing the items. Now the items can be of diff types as per the request. It can be a slice of sites, articles, etc. Which have their individual models. like:

```golang
type ArticleInfo struct {
    ArticleId    uint64   `json:"article_id"`
    ArticleType  string   `json:"article_type"`
    Link         string   `json:"link"`
    Title        string   `json:"title"`
}

type SiteInfo struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Slug    string `json:"slug"`
    SiteURL string `json:"site_url"`
}
```

Is there any way, when parsing the input define the type of `Items` in APIResponse. I don't want to create separate types for individual responses.
Basically want to Unmarshall any incoming response into the APIResponse struct.

Comment: Make Items a slice of (unparsed) json.RawMessage and parse them later.

Comment: I don't exactly understand. Would be greatful if you could show an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change type of the `Items` field to `interface{}`:

```
type APIResponse struct {
    Items          interface{} `json:"items"`
    ...
}
```

Set the response `Items` field to pointer of the desired type. Unmarshal to the response:

```
var articles []ArticleInfo
response := APIResponse{Items: &articles}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &response)
```

Access the articles using variable `articles`.

[Run an example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/wZxSLbkOEDa).

Comment: Can you please explain what does ```APIResponse{Items: &articles}``` exactly mean? What does this do behind the scenes?

Comment: `APIResponse{Items: &articles}` is a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) expression.  The expression evaluates to a value of type `APIResponse` with the `Items` field set to the address of the `articles` variable.